# Amazon Firestick; FireOS; VoiceOver reads "1 of 1" on each element of the list [BUG]

Tags: android, amazon-fire-os, amazon-fire-tv

FireStick **VoiceOver** is a direct AndroidTV **Talkback** competitor for helping disabled people use mobile apps.

When we have a list it reads the **current index** of the element on that list.

[image]

In this specific case it would read aloud:
"appstore - **seven of twenty-four**"
or "row two column one"

I'm using:

```
<androidx.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_carousel"
    android:adapter="@{viewModel.items}" />
```

to display a leanback list of elements on AndroidTV/Amazon FireStick.

It always reads "**one of one**" for every element as if the list had just one position.
What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by a bug in `androidx-recyclerview` library.

Solution:

<s>androidx-recyclerview = "1.0.0"</s>
androidx-recyclerview = "1.1.0"

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force deps.androidx.recyclerview
    }
}
```